# How to update multiple rows

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am trying to use a form to update a the database. Problem with database update is the last row. All rows are updated by the last row. Where is the problem? thx

```
<?php if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {

$material = $_POST['material'];
$cena = $_POST['cena'];
$sql_material  = "UPDATE material_tab SET material=:material, cena=:cena WHERE zapotrzebowanie_id = $id";    
$statement_mat = $pdo->prepare($sql_material);
foreach ($material as $key => $value) {

    $statement_mat -> bindValue(':material', $material[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement_mat -> bindValue(':cena', $cena[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement_mat -> execute();

}

$statement_mat -> closeCursor(); } ?>
```

Form:

```
<?php foreach ($rows_material as $material) { ?>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="material[]" class="big_field required" value="<?php echo $material['material']; ?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cena[]" class="small_field" value="<?php echo $material['cena']; ?>" /></td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: "Problem with database update is the last row" What exactly is the "problem"? Do you get an error?

Comment: It might be because the id never changes in yr loop?

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement says to update .."WHERE zapotrzebowanie_id = $id".  Your sample code never sets the value of $id, nor does your form submit a value for it. You need to include the id in your form to update the record that is displayed on that form, otherwise MySQL has no idea which record to update and will continue to update the record that happens to have zapotrzebowanie_id = $id when that statement is executed.